# Bar graph - cartodiagram in QGIS

Tags: qgis, cartography, qgis-plugins, graph

Can I create a cartodiagram in QGIS 1.7.3? I need one bar graph in every territorial unit of one layer. It must vizualize organization on X and number of research in one organisation. Is it possible? Is there some plugin?

Answer (score 4):

You can display barcharts in QGIS with the Diagrams Overlay plugin. You may have to enable it first. From the Plugins menu, select 'Manage plugins'. Look for the plugin and enable it by clicking on the checkbox.

Then open the Layer Properties, for the layer containing the data to be displayed. On the Overlay tab, you will find the settings for barcharts. More instructions and example output can be found [on this blog page](http://www.qgis.nl/2012/05/02/staafdiagrammen/?lang=en)